# Error while modifying AWS RDS Parameter Group using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, console, rds

I'm tring to use rds-modify-db-parameter-group to modify params:

```
-> % rds-modify-db-parameter-group --db-parameter-group-name=icloset \ 
--parameters="name=tmp_table_size, value={DBInstanceClassMemory/16}, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=max_heap_table_size, value={DBInstanceClassMemory/16}, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=query_cache_type, value=1, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=query_cache_size, value=131072, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=table_open_cache, value=2500, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=join_buffer_size, value={DBInstanceClassMemory/64}, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=thread_cache_size, value={DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=sort_buffer_size, value={DBInstanceClassMemory/64}, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit, value=0, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=innodb_additional_mem_pool_size, value={DBInstanceClassMemory/64}, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct, value=90, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=max_allowed_packet, value=33554432, method=pending-reboot" \
--parameters="name=tx_isolation, value=READ-COMMITTED, method=pending-reboot" --aws-credential-file ./aws-credential.txt
```

But I've have strange error:

> rds-modify-db-parameter-group:  Could not find the resource you requested: Parameter group does not exist

And such group exists - [image]

Answer (score 2):

The default region for rds-cli is us-east-1. Check if you are trying to modify the parameter group of a rds in different region.